# Build DropDown List With JavaScript via XML file

Tags: javascript, xml

I have this XML structure:

```
<sport id="1" name="Soccer">
        <category id="257" name="CountryName">
            <tournament id="11275" uniqueid="722" name="Tournament Name" uniquetournamentname="Tournament Name">
                <team id="5447831" name="Team Name" superId="38529" />
            </tournament>
       </category>
</sport>
```

And saved as soccer.xml, I want to build dropdown list that will show

```
Soccer
-CountryName
--Tournament
---Team
```

Thanks for any helps

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know if you have multiple categories, tournament and teams inside one sports, I assume you don't. This is the simple code to access it in vanilla JS

```
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("soccer.xml"); // your document name
var sports=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("sports");

for (i=0;i<sports.length;i++) { // Just iterate throught each sports
  document.write(sports[i].nodeName+"<br>"+
  "-"+sports[i].childNodes[0].nodeName+"<br>"+
  "--"+sports[i].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeName+"<br>"+
  "---"+sports[i].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeName+"<br>");
}
```